# Why am I getting a "no match for operator*" when using range-based for loop on anything that isn't "*this"?

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing some utility functions for a templated container class for which the iterator seems to be working just fine. For example, the following code compiles and works as expected:
(Class name Mat, containing type T)

```
void scalarFill(T x){
    for(auto& i : *this){
        i = x;
    }
}`
```

However, when I call the range-based for loop on an a newly instantiated container, I get "error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'MatIter')" such as in the following code:

```
static Mat zeros(size_t a){
    Mat<double> result(a);
    for(auto& i: result){
        i = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've explicitly defined the iterator for my class, and there is certainly an 'operator*' function. Is there something I'm missing about how range-based for loops work? The following is a stripped down version of the full program which reproduces the error:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MatIter;

template <class T = double>
class Mat {
    friend class MatIter<T>;

    public:
    size_t columns = 0;
    T* data;

    MatIter<T> begin(){
        return MatIter<T>(*this, 0);
    }
    MatIter<T> end(){
        return MatIter<T>(*this, columns);
    }
    Mat(size_t a){
        columns = a;
        data = new T[a];
    }
    ~Mat(){
        delete []data;
    }
    //This function compiles and works as expected
    void scalarFill(T x){
        for(auto& i : *this){
            i = x;
        }
    }
    //this function throws "error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'Matiter<double>')"
    static Mat zeros(size_t a){
        Mat<double> result(a);
        for(auto& i: result){
            i = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
};

template <class T>
class MatIter{
    public:
    Mat<T>& matrix;
    size_t position;
    MatIter(Mat<T>& mat, size_t pos) : matrix(mat), position(pos){}
    
    bool operator==(MatIter b){
        if(position == b.position) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    bool operator!=(MatIter b){
        if(position != b.position) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    MatIter& operator++(){
        position++;
        return *this;
    }
    MatIter operator++(int){
        MatIter<T> clone(*this);
        position++;
        return clone;
    }
    T & operator*(){
        return matrix.data[position];
    }
};

int main(){
    Mat<> test(7);
    test.scalarFill(5);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < test.columns-1; i++){
        printf("%g, ", test.data[i]);
    }
    printf("%g\n", test.data[test.columns-1]);

    test = Mat<double>::zeros(7);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < test.columns-1; i++){
        printf("%g, ", test.data[i]);
    }
    printf("%g\n", test.data[test.columns-1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This fails because at the point where the compiler sees this loop, it has not yet seen a definition for the `MatIter` template; `MatIter<double>` is therefore an incomplete type, so the compiler doesn't know about the `operator*` member function yet.

However, the `result` variable shouldn't even be `Mat<double>` here, it should just be `Mat` (which is the same as `Mat<T>`).  Changing the type of `result` to `Mat` solves the problem.  It forces the compiler to wait to figure out if the body is valid until it knows what `T` is, and by then `MatIter` has a definition, and the compiler can find the `operator*` function.

Then you have a double-free problem because your `Mat` template violates the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) -- the implicit copy and move constructor/assignment operations cause dual ownership of the `data` pointer.  The object returned out of `Mat::zeros()` is used as the source of move-assignment to `test` in `main()`.  This copies the `data` pointer to `test` but then the returned temporary is destroyed, which causes the `data` pointer to be deleted, freeing the allocated memory.  Then `test` is destroyed, and the same pointer value is deleted a second time.